# SFML Could not dispatch a message to the daemon

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

```
C:\dev\cpp\SFMLandroid\SFML\examples\android>gradle build
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 3 busy and 11 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not dispatch a message to the daemon.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

C:\dev\cpp\SFMLandroid\SFML\examples\android>
```

I'm having this error with SFML.
https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Building-SFML-for-Android

I did every single thing in this page correctly. But i get error in the last part. What should i do?

Edit:It's because of ram. There is nothing you guys can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. It's because i don't have enough ram.

Comment: You can also accept your own question, I think that will be unlocked in 48 hours or something like that. Now, somebody else with the same problem can find your answer and they don't have to ask themselves, that's essentially what Stack Overflow is all about. If your answer is properly tagged and has a good title and description of the problem, often there is somebody who knows the solution and will answer. That didn't happen in this case but don't be discouraged.